# Preferred way to convert reStructuredText to PDF

Tags: pdf, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I was searching for a simple way to convert a single .rst file to pdf with default styling, but couldn't find a way. Here is what I tried:

#### rst2pdf

I am getting a syntax error inside rst2pdf, probably written for python2 (which I don't have now):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rst2pdf/createpdf.py", line 695
  except ValueError, v:
                   ^
```

<strike>It looks rst2pdf is not maintained anymore, the latest commit on github is from a year ago.</strike> (*Edit:* it IS maintained, see comments. Sorry for that, I was mistaken)

#### make latexpdf

This ought to generate pdf from all the documents, but whatever.. After installing some dependencies (`latexmk, texlive-latex-extra and texlive-full`), still gives me errors, like:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./xdocument.out)
(./xdocument.out)
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyOrg@maketitle ...idth }{1pt}\ifsphinxpdfoutput 
                                                  \begingroup \def \\{, } \d...
l.51 \sphinxtableofcontents

?
```

Html generation just works fine (with `make html`). The makefile was not written by me, but it seems like some default provided by some sphinx tools. Is there an easy way to convert a single rst file to pdf?

**EDIT**

I wonder why did pip3 allow me to install rst2pdf in he first place, but at the end I did it again using python2, and it works fine. So now the question is rather if there is a way to do it without rst2pdf.

Comment: What about using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/)?

Comment: the `\ifsphinxpdfoutput` and related latex code was removed in a commit merged into Sphinx 1.6.1. Thus, try again with latest Sphinx (current is 1.6.2). Also, make sure after upgrade to clean the latex build repertory (simplest is make clean latexpdf).

Comment: Rst2pdf is actively maintained but we're still working on updating to python 3.

Comment: https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype